# how add some data inside sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add some data inside my database .. i want to add the "admin" as default username and password for my program .. so that no need to register on first run of my program when i input username and password to my Edittext it will continue to go inside the admin activity..

this my coding to add some data

```
        UserCrud uCrud = new UserCrud(this);
        User user = new User();
        user.loguser = "admin";
        user.logpass = "admin";
        uCrud.insert(user);
```

this my crud operation to insert data inside my database

```
public class UserCrud {

private DBHelper dbHelper;

public UserCrud(Context context){
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
}

public int insert(User user){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(User.KEY_priv, user.privl);
    values.put(User.KEY_username, user.username);
    values.put(User.KEY_usertype, user.usertype);
    values.put(User.KEY_sex, user.sex);
    values.put(User.KEY_usercompany, user.usercompany);
    values.put(User.KEY_usermail, user.usermail);
    values.put(User.KEY_usercontact, user.usercontact);
    values.put(User.KEY_useradd, user.useradd);
    values.put(User.KEY_loguser, user.loguser);
    values.put(User.KEY_logpass, user.logpass);
    values.put(User.KEY_logconfirm, user.logconfirmm);

    long user_Id = db.insert(User.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    return (int) user_Id;
}
```

but when i run my app nothing happens ..

Comment: The code you've shown looks OK. The problem is elsewhere. Why do you think that nothing happens?

Comment: on my second run i got error and the error in my logcat is pointing to nothing

Comment: No Exceptions in logcat?

Comment: why is your insert() method returns `id`? You don't need to return anything if you are inserting a row in Db

Comment: Don't You need to call db.open() before db.insert ? Apurva - insert returns last_insert_rowid, it's not required to be returned, but there is nothing wrong with that as well.

Comment: Certainly there is something to see in logcat if you get an error.  A SQLiteException perhaps?  Also, what does your User table creation SQL look like?

Comment: thanks to all  answers.. i already fixed it but i have one problem .. everytime i run my app it always inserted new data of username and password how can make it to create only 1

Comment: Instead of **blindly** calling the insert method upon each app start, simply check (query the user on the db and see if it returns any row) if the record is already present. **IF NOT**, then proceed to insert.